# When does SCTP timeout?

Tags: sctp

Assuming timers set like in the Linux implementation or as suggested in RFC4960:

**When does an idle SCTP association timeout, when the peer disappears?**

**a)** let’s assume HEARTBEAT is switched off for all destination addresses.

I guess it never does, because nothing is sent, so nothing gets lost.

**b)** with normal HEARTBEATs, both peers single homed.

- Association.Max.Retrans is 10 times
- RTO.Max is 60 seconds

After HEARTBEAT kicks in (when?) the upper limit is something related to 10×60s (=10 minutes). Who knows the details?

**c)** is it different if one or both sides are multihomed? Or if the association has a lot of data to send?

I’m not sure if the multihoming case is different at all (timeouts faster or slower?). – And if data is to be sent: I guess the timeout is still the same minus average time for the HEARTBEAT to kick in.

Comment: Maybe you can get some information form:https://github.com/sctplab/usrsctp/blob/master/Manual.md